# Assembly language bug

Tags: assembly

;this program prints only the first word from the file. I don't know how to find the end of a file or how to read the whole string,even it has spaces.

```
.data
open_mode DB "r",0
file_name1 DB "prb4.txt",0
linie DB 0
format DB "%s ",0
.code
start:
            push offset open_mode
            push offset file_name1
            call fopen
            add esp,8
            mov ecx,eax
            et_read:    
            push offset linie
            push offset format
            push eax
            call fscanf
            add esp,12
            push offset linie
            push offset format
            call printf
            add esp,4
            loop et_read


push 0
call exit
end start
```

Comment: I suggest that you should implement what you want in C first, and then translate it into assembly.

Comment: You do realize that you only allocated one byte to hold the string that you are reading with `fscanf` don't you? (`linie DB 0`) That's going to be a problem. And `linie` should be declared in a `bss` section, not `data` section since it's writable.

Answer (score 0):

A few quick observations

- You need to allocate space for the data you are reading. Currently `linie` is only one byte. You can do something like the following

  linie DB 80 dup(?) ; allocate an 80 byte buffer
- Use `fgets` to read a line at a time. Make sure your `linie` buffer is large enough for the line
- You can check the return value of fgets to determine the `eof`
- Remember to close your file once you are done.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't find any syntax for fgets in assemby language(just in C).

Comment: @user5640022, fgets is just another library call like fscanf, fopen etc. Check the C signature of the function arguments and how they need to be passed. I think there are a few posts here on stackoverflow on calling fgets from assembly language

Comment: @user5640022: you can always just look at compiler output if you're not sure what the "normal" way to do something is.  Although "normally" you'd only write an inner loop in asm, and the rest of the program in C (or any other language).  Writing whole programs in asm is mainly useful as a learning exercise.

Comment: Put the buffer in the `.bss` section, instead of `.data`.  You don't need 80 bytes of zeros in the executable.  `section .bss` / `linie resb 80`.